# Soap request message in Ansi C

Tags: c, soap

I need to consume a Java WebService from C.

I created simple C client program and I want to construct the SOAP request that should be sent to SOAP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP is not easy in C. You'll want to use a toolkit, of course. I recommend [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) as one of the best.